# python pandas dataframe not outputting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

this following python code dosent output what it is supposed to output(new dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

try:
    file = pd.read_csv("customers.csv")
except:
    pass


customers = {"name":[""],
             "last":[""],
             "age_range":[0],
             "emails":[""]}

df_customers = pd.DataFrame(customers)


def add_customer(df,name,last,age=np.nan,email=np.nan):
    df_customers = df.append({"name":name,
             "last":last,
             "age_range":age,
             "emails":email},ignore_index=True)




add_customer(df_customers,"mohamed","miboun",email="mohamedwapana@gmail.com")
print(df_customers)
```

i try to append customer's info but its just outputting the dataframe with no values in it.
please help.

Comment: 1) The function does not return the appended DataFrame.  2) The function output is not assigned to a variable. 3) Why is 'email' defaulted to a float value; surely it should be a string?

Comment: `NaN` is fine for missing data for "object" columns, that's what pandas uses as the default for object columns. (i.e. `pd.Series(['s', None]).add('foo')`). You could use `None` too but idk having a single NA representation is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the ways you can build the function you want:

```
def add_customer(df,name,last,age=np.nan,email=None):
    # First, taking care to manipulate the last index and add a new line
    index = " "
    if df.iloc[-1, 0] == "":
        index = 0
    else:
        index = df.index[-1] + 1
    
    # Now, we simply assign each respective column
    df.loc[index, 'name'] = name
    df.loc[index, 'last'] = last
    df.loc[index, 'age'] = age
    df.loc[index, 'email'] = email


add_customer(df_customers,"mohamed","miboun",email="mohamedwapana@gmail.com")
df_customers
```

This function will add a new line and fill it with the customer's information.

In the named paramether for "email" the dafault value should be None and note np.nan as you had inserted in your example. Note that np.nan refers **only** to numerical values